# What's with dinosaurs in Vietnam?

Tags: lyrics, cover, black-sabbath

There's an awesome song by Black Sabbath called [Into the Void](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Into_the_Void_(Black_Sabbath_song)). It's been covered by a few bands, including [Monster Magnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Magnet).

In Monster Magnet's version, which is also super awesome, there are additional lyrics. He keeps talking about dinosaurs in Vietnam. What? Why?

Here are the original lyrics ([from Google Play Music](https://play.google.com/music/preview/T3byk2nprxdnuuxyeyrdcvpbb3u?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics)):

> Rocket engines burning fuel so fast
>   Up into the night sky they blast
>   Through the universe the engines whine
>   Could it be the end of man and time
>   Back on earth the flame of life burns low
>   Everywhere is misery and woe
>   Pollution kills the air, the land, the sea
>   Man prepares to meet his destiny
>
> Rocket engines burning fuel so fast
>   Up into the black sky so vast
>   Burning metal through the atmosphere
>   Earth remains in worry, hate and fear
>   With the hateful battles raging on
>   Rockets flying to the glowing sun
>   Through the empires of eternal void
>   Freedom from the final suicide
>
> Freedom fighters sent out to the sun
>   Escape from brainwashed winds and pollution
>   Leave the earth to all its sin and hate
>   Find another world where freedom waits
>
> Past the stars in fields of ancient void
>   Through the shields of darkness where they find
>   Love upon a land a world unknown
>   Where the sons of freedom make their home
>   Leave the earth - to satan and his slaves
>   Leave them to their future in their graves
>   Make a home where love is there to stay
>   Peace and happiness in every day

Here's the modified Monster Magnet version ([from LyricsFreak](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/m/monster+magnet/into+the+void_20286480.html)):

> Oh!
>   Everywhere is unreal.
>   The fame of my birth known.
>   Oh!
>
> Those dinosaurs in Vietnam!
>   Those dinosaurs in Vietnam!
>   Those dinosaurs in Vietnam!
>   Aah
>
> Come on and show me.
>   Come on and show me.
>   A man who has to leave his destiny.
>   A man who has to leave his destiny!
>   Aah
>
> Come on and show me!
>   Show me now!
>
> Yeah the techno sluts are dancin' in hell.
>   The techno sluts are dancin' in hell.
>   Oh yeah!
>   Into the twentieth century yeah!
>
> Aw poor baby.
>   Poor baby.
>   Yeah you've all bit the dust, ha ha.
>   Ain't no soul comin' back motherf***er.
>
> Woo
>   Aah
>
> Into the void
>   Aw
>   Woo!
>
> Rocket engines burning fuel so fast,
>   Up into the night sky they blast.
>   Through the universe the engines whine,
>   Could it be the end of man and time?
>   Back on earth the flame of life burns low,
>   Everywhere is misery and woe.
>   Pollution kills the air, the land and sea.
>   Man prepares to meet his destiny.
>
> Into the void!
>   Yeah!
>   Woo!
>
> Rocket engines burning fuel so fast,
>   Up into the night sky so vast.
>   Burning metal through the atmosphere,
>   Earth remains in worry, hate, and fear.
>   With the hateful battles raging on,
>   Rockets flying to the glowing sun!
>   Through the empires of eternal void,
>   Freedom from the final suicide!
>
> Into the void!
>   Yeah!
>   Down to the void!
>   Woo yeah!
>   Aw yeah!
>
> You're a f***ing genius!
>   That's right!
>
> Dinosaurs in Vietnam.
>   Dinosaurs in Vietnam.
>   Dinosaurs in Vietnam.
>   Dinosaurs in Vietnam.
>   Oh!
>
> That's all that can be saw. Ha ha!
>   Oh yeah that's right.
>   Yeah

As you can see, he repeats "dinosaurs in Vietnam" quite a few times. Why? What does that have to do with anything else? They've essentially omitted the last two verses and replaced them with this other stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dave Wyndorf, songwriter, lead vocalist, and a guitarist for Monster Magnet, explains in [an interview with Adam De Ville for *Collide*](http://www.collideartandculture.com/#!Interview-Dave-Wyndorf-on-Cobras-and-Fire-Drugs-Marilyn-Manson-Courtney-Love-and-Spinal-Tap-Moments/c1lt4/561b26d50cf2c6c6436f7e7d):

> **Adam De Ville:** “Dinosaurs in Vietnam!”
>
> **Dave Wyndorf:** Yeah! **I just pictured a T-Rex stomping through Vietnam and chomping
>   everything up during the war. I made it all up on the spot** and Dave
>   Sardy was totally into it - he knew what I was going for. The original
>   version must have been like half an hour long and it was cut down.

Comment: I found the previous question in that interview pretty relevant as well: "How did the Black Sabbath cover of 'Into The Void' come about years later with Monster Magnet?" Excerpts:

I was listening to a lot of the band Suicide at the time - one of the best bands ever...was asked to do a track for an upcoming Sabbath tribute album (Nativity in Black Vol. II)...“I’m gonna do a Suicide thing with this and freak it out!”...Dave Sardy (Producer and Mixer for Marilyn Manson, Nine Inch Nails, Rolling Stones and Nick Cave...I just thought it would be funny to have some guy screaming in the background